# Tool (SSIS or Powershell) to migrate large number of documents with metadata into SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, migration

I'm looking to migrate 400GB of files (Word, PDF, etc.) from a network file share into SharePoint 2010. The target farm has two WFE's. My question is whether the fastest (in terms of the migration window) and most reliable solution would be to create multiple jobs of:

A) Build an SSIS job that picked up each file and insert through the SharePoint web services? 
B) Build a PowerShell script that picked up each file and insert using the PowerShell API for SharePoint?
C) Other?

There has to be some logic to also read an associated metadata files in order to fill some SharePoint attributes, which may make an off the shelf third party tool unsuitable.

Comment: C) Surface the information via search?

Comment: That would be an option, however the department prefers to maintain all documentation inside one system (SharePoint)